# Google Chrome executeScript that returns multiple values with one query?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following Google Chrome executeScript.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
tabs[0].id,
{code: 'document.querySelectorAll(".col-9.col-md-10")[3].innerText'}, citationResult => {
              console.log(citationResult);
});
```

This code gets the 4th element which has the classes `col-9` AND `col-md-10' and then gets the inner text of that element. That is a string.

I would like a generalized query which instead returns every element which has  `col-9` AND `col-md-10'. However, when I try something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
tabs[0].id,
{code: 'document.querySelectorAll(".col-9.col-md-10")}, citationResult => {
              console.log(citationResult);
});
```

I seem to get an empty array.

Is there a way to get those four elements returned rather than just getting the innerText of that single element?

Comment: DOM elements and complex types can't be transferred so you need to extract the data as an array/object of simple types like strings.

Answer (score 1):

As [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) said, I needed to return an array of primitives. This is what solved my problem.

```
'var x = document.querySelectorAll(".col-9.col-md-10"); const finalArray = []; \n' +
            'for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {\n' +
            '  finalArray.push(x[i].innerText);\n' +
            '} finalArray;'
```